# should i do SQLQuerys or dumping all the data on a list/vector java

Tags: java, mysql, list, vector

Im working on a small project.
I was wondering what is the best "technique" to manipulate data from a MySQL database:

1) Should I use results sets and execute querys over the database or
2) I should dump all the data from the database on vectors/list

Imagine i have a table with employees, should i dump all that data on a Vector of employees or just use querys to list all the employees on a `jtable`?

Comment: How large are your tables? How often are they updated?

Comment: some tables should grow exponencially. And i want the program to be as fast as possible

Answer (score 0):

If your table is not getting updated too frequently then Cache the result if the size of table is not too large. Otherwise you can query the database every time.